# Installing at some custom location using apt-get

Tags: installation, apt

To install a library I do sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev and it is installed at some default location. I want to install it at some location other then default location. Is it possible to do so.

Or I can also build it from source but I am unable to find source code of this library.

Please help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, it is not possible to change the locations of files using apt-get. Paths are part of the package. To change them you will need to modify the package itself (which might or might not be easy, depending on the package).
2. To download the source code for your package, all you need to do is `sudo apt-get source libmysqlclient-dev`.

Hope this helps