# Change / Choose install path for a .deb

Tags: installation, 12.10, xubuntu, games, deb

I would like to know if it is possible to choose where a **.deb** file will be installed, or if it is possible to move it after the installation to another directory without troubles for the app.

I am asking that because I am running *Ubuntu* on a 32Go's *SSD*, and I would like to install some games from Humble Bundle on my other *HDD*.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/156927/installing-at-some-custom-location-using-apt-get

Comment: There is a similar question also at superuser.com answering that question: http://superuser.com/questions/155537/install-deb-packages-in-another-directory-or-equivalent

Comment: I'm sorry, I've not checked SuperUser for this question. I thought it was something pretty specific to the operating system and it was the right place to search/ask it. But thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a similar [Q&A at superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/155537/install-deb-packages-in-another-directory-or-equivalent) dealing with that question. A [more specific question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156927/installing-at-some-custom-location-using-apt-get) was asked also here at askubuntu.com.

Your choices are:

- **Use symlinks**. Open the *.deb package with the archive manager. This tells you where the files go. Move those directories to your external harddisc and put a symlink at the origin. Be careful to move only directories from your games and not shared libraries or so!
- **Mount** your external hardrive or some of its folders (a second time) at the game's path. E.g. `/usr/share/games` might be good candidate for your external harddisc. You can use the bind option, e.g.:

  `sudo mount --bind /media/external-hardisc/usr-share-games /usr/share/games`
- Don't use a *.deb package, but install directly **from source** to a directory of your choice.
- Use the `dpkg` **parameter** `--root` to change the install location. The man page says:

  --root=dir
        Changing   root  changes  instdir  to  dir  and  admindir  to
        dir/var/lib/dpkg.

  There is no guarantee that this will work. The program might not be able to deal with the different location.

(This list of solutions is not exhaustive.)

Answer (score 2):

As I know extracted files like libraries and executables must be extracted into fixed directories that use these files during program execution. Also I think this debs contains large resources and lightweight files separately. For example many games unpack their resources to `/opt` directory. You can mount your HDD as `/opt` that store resources there:

Here is example:

```
sudo mv /opt /media/your_hdd/opt
sudo mkdir /opt
```

And check mount:

```
sudo mount --bind /media/your_hdd/opt /opt
```

if this works add `mount --bind /media/your_hdd/opt /opt` to `/etc/rc.local` before `exit 0` to auto mount after each system boot.