# Change installation path / move programs

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, steam, disk-usage, storage

I am using a 120GB SSD and a 1TB HDD.
I created Ubuntu (home directory, etc.) on the SSD and stored some data (music, photos) on the HDD. Sadly the SSD is now full because of my games and programs.
I searched to change the installation path of games or programs or to move some of them to the HDD but this seems to be impossible (without slowing it or some programs not working because they look for a specific library path).

I know that I can move my whole home folder to the HDD but this will slow my system.
I read that Ubuntu doesn't have a C:/Programs folder like Windows and in Ubuntu the files are splitted on their purpose (all libraries in one folder, all executable in another.. etc.). So is there a way to free up space beneath uninstalling programs? 
Maybe the mount process described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236094/change-choose-install-path-for-a-deb) could help? I am fairly new to Ubuntu, so which folder could I mount and how to do this? What exactly does it do?

Additional:
If I try to add another directory for Steam (for my games) only the SSD gets shown and I can't toggle the view to get my HDD shown. Beneath that I could change the directory Spotify downloaded its music to the HDD.

Comment: Thats really difficult to do. From where did you install your games?

Comment: I installed my games using the official Steam for Linux.

Comment: See my answer, hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a folder on your HDD e.g. "my_games". Then copy all the contents from `/home/YOURUSERNAME/.local/share/Steam` to `"my_games"` on your HDD.

Then open Steam:

`>> Settings >> Downloads >> Content Libraries`

Click on `ADD LIBRARY FOLDER` and select `"my_games"` (your HDD is mounted / found inside the `/media` folder(!)) on your HDD. Then select the old library folder and click on `REMOVE LIBRARY FOLDE`

After closing the menu remove the old folder with: `rm -r /home/YOURUSERNAME/.local/share/Steam`

Comment: thank you for your answer. just for understanding: is there a difference between your command and deleting the folder with the help of the gui?

Comment: No it's totally the same, but I am used to the console and way faster ;) But it's up to you what you use!

Answer (score 0):

That would be hard to do. Error-prone. You need to be a pro to do it. Better find some other way to free space. BTW, my Ubuntu lives on 40GB and has tons of apps - what did you fill it with? Steam games? They should go to HDD.
Mount your HDD to some folder like /mnt/games and move games there. I will not give instructions because you need to know mounting to use Linux. Search and study.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the equivalent of `C:\Program Files` is `/usr`, which you can mount on a separate partition. Just make another `ext4` partition of a reasonable size during installation and mark it for mounting on `/usr`. Doing this post-install can be done, if you move everything to the new partition before mounting. 
This can be done for most folders under `/`, indeed some people keep `/home`, `/usr`, `/boot` and `/var` on separate partitions.

As for Steam (assuming the Linux version), you can have a Library folder on other partitions, even NTFS partitions. For Steam on Wine, have you added the other partition mount points as drives in Wine?